# Transport layer Services and Application Layer services

Tags: web-services, http, tcp

I am working with web services right now. We have two types of services, one over HTTP and other over TCP. when Trying to understand the difference between these two, as per my understanding, services over TCP work at the transport layer i.e they transmit data over two ends. So in that case services over TCP will directly transfer data between two ends. But i am not so much clear on services over HTTP. I know we have a Client server model, REST, SOAP and HTTP is the protocol that transmits data but i am not able to properly relate the concept of services over HTTP!

Can anyone please help with an analogy which explains the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As John Saunders is trying to allude to, I would agree that it is more important to understand the abstractions these protocols provide, rather than specific "Layer" they may be called in certain model (OSI). While the general model helps and applies, it doesn't provide specific details for actual protocols.

Having said that, the difference between so called **Transport Layer Services** using `TCP` vs **Application Layer Services** using `HTTP`, IMHO boils down to the comparisons between `TCP` and `HTTP` itself.

I'll start be saying that I hope it is known to anyone even vaguely familiar with these protocols, that `HTTP` is higher level abstraction than `TCP` and in fact it relies on `TCP/IP` itself. Hence `HTTP` clearly inherits *certain* feature like reliability from `TCP/IP`.

Now the contrast -

**TCP Service**

- **Design your own application level protocol** - You design your own application level protocol.. For example, how will Client request operation to add an employee? How will Client request to find a given employee? etc...  How do you indicate the format in which data can be exchanged between client and server? How will you even distinguish metadata (like request information) from data?
- **Efficiency** - Can be efficient and compact in transmission of data. Since you define your own application layer protocol, Can be anything from binary to string to XML to anything else you can dream of.

`HTTP` for example, is built on top of `TCP`, in layman terms, mostly using Key Value pair style request *headers*.. vs `SOAP`, where much of information is passed as *message envelope* and *message body* (Which is why `SOAP` can be over `HTTP` as well as other protocols like `Message Queues`)

- **Performance** - Given the possibility of having very compact application layer protocol, it can be relatively fast as well. For really high throughput, high performance, latency sensitive intranet applications, this can be a deciding factor.
- **Development Effort** - Along with the flexibility, you certainly end up writing more code, as you attempt to define and implement your own application layer protocol.

**HTTP Service**

- **Larger parts of application protocol are defined for you** - You design your application over well defined HTTP protocol. Typically `HTTP Get` would mean querying for a resource. Query filters in request url can be used for searches. `HTTP POST, PUT and DELETE` similarly have specific, well defined semantics.
- **Error / Fault handling** - Even error are indicated using standards defined in `HTTP` protocol.. Like Status Code `200` (Success) vs `400` (BadRequest).
- **Efficiency** - Can be quite verbose. Protocols defines almost every aspect of how the request must be defined.. and is typically text based..
- **Development and Tools support** - `HTTP` can make it easier to use existing, vast variety of tools to send, receive and debug requests (`Fiddler` or `Charles Proxy` are famous `HTTP` debugging tools).
- **Internet / Firewall Friendly** - `HTTP` is typically used at port 80 (although in theory can be other port as well). Which makes it more suitable not only for intranet applications, where you may have more control over firewalls and ports you open.. but also for accessing those services over Internet, because port 80 is typically open on *almost* every machine in the world...
- **Co-existence of multiple services** - `HTTP` is so widely used, that it is expected multiple applications / services on a given machine to use it.. OS typically have special support built into the OS to handle this (`http.sys` on `Windows`) and you don't have to worry about one application / service stepping on another, by accidentally using the same port (one will fail in such case). Port negotiation between client and server is typically not an issue in this case, because HTTP is expected to be at port 80.
- **Securing the communication channel** - When it comes to securing the communication, again there is well defined way to establish the same.. i.e. `HTTPS`. Unlike `TCP/IP` based service, you don't have to invent your own scheme to encrypt the communication between client and server.
- **Hosting the service** - In theory, there are more ways to host an `HTTP` service, than a `TCP` service, again due to `HTTP` web applications already being a common scenario, which web servers like `IIS` already cater to. Your `HTTP` service can take advantage of countless out of the box features which web servers like `IIS` already have.. Recycling, Authentication, Resource Management, Request Filtering, Caching, Dynamic Compression and Logging etc etc etc.. you get for free with `HTTP` services hosted on any of the mature web server products.
- **Interoperability Across Platforms / Technology stacks** - With `HTTP`, it would be far easier to use a mix of any technology stack, again because the implementation of the Protocol will be typically supported on various platforms.. from `Linux` / `Unix` to `Windows`.. or from `.Net` to `Java` to `Ruby`.. You'll get benefit from existing tools and technologies present on these platforms which support `HTTP`.. Hence `Http` can be the de facto choice, if, for example, you expect server to be in `.Net` on `Windows`, but clients to be in `Java` on `Unix`.

I could go on.. This is by no means an exhaustive list, and I am sure that many others could add plenty more to this.. But hopefully this gives you a good idea for what you were looking.. One can clearly see, that this can be a very deep topic.. Based on your response and time, I may edit this answer in future.. or encourage others to update it, as they see fit.

**Side note -** It is interesting to note, that even though `HTTP` adds plenty over `TCP/IP` to make it a great and ubiquitous choice for application protocol.. There is always scope for more / higher level abstraction.. So much so that, there are other, newer service protocols, which are built on top of `HTTP`. For example - [`Odata`](http://www.odata.org/). Look at `OData` if you are curious..

And of course, in todays world of services, the discussion will not be complete without the mention of [`REST`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

**EDIT: Another interesting side note -** If you are building on `Windows` platform, and using `.Net` framework, there are frameworks like `Windows Communication Foundation` a.k.a. `WCF`, which try to provide such abstractions, that you can swap out your choice of communication protocol (Client and Server choice must still match), from `HTTP` to `TCP` to `MSMQ` to `IPC` etc, with mere configuration changes, or host same service over multiple communication protocols by creating multiple *endpoints*. Refer to [Understanding various types of WCF bindings](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/VE8a200713-Understanding-various-types-of-WCF-bindings.html) for high level overview and comparison of various, out of the box, options `WCF` provides.

Answer (score 1):

When working with TCP/IP and protocols layered on top of it, I would take the 7-layer model with a grain of salt. The true number of layers will differ, and will not match up with the classic OSI model.

For instance, HTTP is built on top of the TELNET protocol, which is layered on top of TCP. Does that make TELNET a Presentation-layer protocol? No, it's an Application-layer protocol that happens to have another Application-layer protocol built on top of it.

And then we run SOAP over HTTP. Or, if we want, we can run SOAP over TCP/IP. So what layer is SOAP? Is that layer 8 or is that layer 9?

Comment: What's the story with the downvotes? In what way is my answer not accurate or not useful? The fact is, TCP/IP and the modern protocols used on the web do **not** follow the "classic" OSI seven-layer model, as they layer on each other at the application layer.

Comment: i couldn't understand your answer.. my question is simple. Howe do services at transport layer differ than that of http layer?  I get your point that TCP/IP does not follow OSI seven-layer model  but how do services over TCP and services over HTTP differ ?

Comment: Why do you believe that they differ?

Answer (score 1):

As You asked, I'll try to explain by analogy, while not repeating previous answers too much.

Let's say we have helpdesk (service) reachable by phone call (TCP) and by SMS (HTTP). From Your (application) point of view You should get the same information independent of which communication method You chose. But there are differencies how this communication will be going, because phone call (TCP) is **statefull** channel, while SMS (HTTP) is **stateless**:

- once phone call is established, information exchange will continue until hang'up;
- SMS message must contain all relevant information to get a usefull response.

To introduce **state** into SMS channel, additional steps at helpdesk level are required, for example, You'll be assigned ticket number, which You must send with each related SMS (HTTP cookie/session) - this won't be handled authomatically by GSM network. This *state* is handled by helpdesk's and Your (service and application) logic.

Both service types have advantages and pitfalls. And both should work - preferance depends on actual use-case.

There is no too much difference what means are used to exchange data (You can even exchange mails using post office, if latency is acceptable). In practice it means You can use `ping` (ICMP) or DNS queries, or emails to exchange data - as long as Your application knows how to use/decode such channel.

I think [John Saunders in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613787/4308649) refered to [7 layer OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), an I think his point is correct.

This analogy is not 100% correct, I tried to explain the idea: the difference is how the **state** is preserved (by protocol itself, or by application/framework).