# What is the proper terminology (Application Layer, Transport layer, etc.) when "wrapping" one protocol inside another?

Tags: network-programming, terminology, network-protocols

I am designing an application that communicates with devices over various connection types / transport mechanisms. For example, USB Virtual COM, serial port, and TCP connections. In each case I will be using a custom/device-specific application protocol (e.g. to send commands, receive data, etc.) passed through the underlying transport. For the cases mentioned so far it seems pretty clear to me that the "Application Protocol" is the proprietary command/response one and TCP connection (or serial port or "whatever magically transports the bytes") is the Transport Protocol.

However, what is the best way to talk about intermediate protocols, for example, when encapsulating the aforementioned proprietary application layer protocol inside of another application layer protocol like SSH, HTTP, or SSL/TLS?

[This answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613589/transport-layer-services-and-application-layer-services#answer-27613787) suggests that:

1. It's not so important what you call it (with which OSI layer it is associated)
2. Something like this might be correctly described as an application layer protocol that happens to have another application layer protocol built on top of it.

Bottom line: **How should I label this detail in the GUI?** Perhaps one of the following?

*✔ "Tunnel" or "Tunneling Protocol" (as suggested by @EJP)*

Other possibilities included:

- "Application protocol" (misleading because there is actually a higher level protocol that would be more appropriately given this name)
- "Transport protocol" (may be misleading since there would be a lower level protocol like TCP underneath, which is usually what this name would make me think of)
- "Encapsulation" or "Encapsulation protocol"
- "Wrapping protocol" (similar to above)
- "Underlying protocol" (vague / ambiguous -- there are probably many more underlying protocols...TCP, IP, Ethernet, ...)
- "Protocol" (too generic?)

Nothing seems to jump out at me as fitting.

**Update:** As @EJP pointed out, SSL/TLS is an application layer protocol not a transport protocol; the question now reflects this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, what is the best way to talk about intermediate protocols, for example, when encapsulating the aforementioned proprietary application layer protocol inside of another application layer protocol like SSH or HTTP or even another transport layer protocol like SSL/TLS?

Every protocol you have mentioned here is an application layer protocol.

You might want to use the word 'tunnelling'.

> It's not so important what you call it (with which OSI layer it is associated)

There's no reason to associate it with any of the OSI layers at all. The OSI model is for the OSI protocol suite, which is defunct, *ergo* so is the model. It's unfortunate that generations of teachers have taught it as though it was a fundamental law of nature. It isn't. If you're using TCP/IP, it has its own layer model, for example, and even the OSI guys admit that nobody ever knew what went into the presentation layer.

Comment: I will update the question to mark SSL/TLS as an application protocol as well. I guess I have heard people talk about it casually as a transport protocol, but functionally that doesn't make any sense.
"Tunneling" seems like another reasonable contender (it lines up with SSH's terminology), though it might misleadingly make people think of [IP tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_tunnel) / VPN stuff.

Comment: That's not misleading., it is another exact example. It's just tunnelling at a different layer.

Comment: Right; I just meant that it is different. The users of this application are likely to be scientifically knowledgeable/technical but not necessarily familiar with the inner workings of computer and network systems, so I'm trying my best to avoid anything that could confuse them. Perhaps I shouldn't try to accomplish that via terminology in this case though; it might make more sense just to hide advanced options by default. Thanks for your suggestions. In lieu of others I am going to mark this as the accepted answer.